# digits in long to base64 characters

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, base64

I am working on a small task which requires some base64 encoding. I am trying to do it in head but getting lost .

I have a 13 digit number in java long format say: 1294705313608 , 1294705313594 , 1294705313573

I do some processing with it, bascially I take this number append it with stuff put it in a byte array and then convert it to base64 using:

```
String b64String = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(bArray);
```

Now , I know that for my original number, the first 3 digits would never change. So 129 is constant in above numbers. I want to find out how many chars corresponding to those digits would not change in the resultant base64 string.

Code to serialize long to the byte array. I ignore the first 2 bytes since they are always 0:

bArray[0] = (byte) (time >>> 40);
    bArray[1] = (byte) (time >>> 32);
    bArray[2] = (byte) (time >>> 24);
    bArray[3] = (byte) (time >>> 16);
    bArray[4] = (byte) (time >>> 8);
    bArray[5] = (byte) (time >>> 0);

Thanks.

Notes:
I know that base64 would take 6 bits and make one character out of it. So if first 3 digits do not change in long how many chars would not change in base64.
This in NOT a HW assignment, but I am not very familiar with encoding.

Comment: I think this is homework, but not tagged as so.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to serialize the long to the byte array with the other "stuff"?

Comment: @dkarp:  I have posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

1290000000000 is `10010110001011001111111011110010000000000` in binary.
1299999999999 is `10010111010101110000010011100011111111111` in binary.

Both are 41 bits long, and they differ after the first 7 bits.  Your shift places bits 41-48 in the first byte, which will always be `00000001`.  The following byte will always be `00101110`, `00101101`, or `00101110`.  So you've got the leading 14 bits in common across all your possible array values, which (at 6 bits per encoded base64 char) means 2 characters in common in the encoded string.

Comment: Thnx dkarpp, I am confused between "they differ after the first 7 bits" & "you've got the leading 14 bits in common across all your possible array values" ... 7 bits can make a 3 digit number and hence I can understand that first 3 digits in the long doesnt change ....So the 7 bits would correspond to only 1 base64char .. so only 1 char should not change ?? .. Can you explain once more how did you derive the 14 bits ? . thnx again..I programmed it and as you can see the long is a timestmp ..

Comment: so for 2 different times I got these numbers. the nos are after appendng actual byte array wth more bytes so ignore its lenght:

Comment: You split up those 7 bits with your serialization logic.  1 bit went into the first byte, the other 6 went into the second byte.  With that 1 bit in the first byte came 7 bits of all `0`s.  So you have 7 bits of your `long` that don't change *and 7 bits of leading `0` as well*.

Comment: shift places bits 41-48 in the first byte is correct .. it will not be 00000001 .. it will be whatever the time variable has in bits 41-48. Those 7 bits go into bArray[0] .. and hence I am saying 1 base64 character

Comment: The time variable has `00000001` in bits 41-48.  It has `00101110`, `00101101`, or `00101110` in bits 33-40.  The thing you're missing is that your serialization algorithm is grabbing the first nonzero bit from the long as well as 7 bits of leading `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you're on the right track.  I think what you want to do is convert a long to a byte array, then convert the byte array to Base64.

[How do I convert Long to byte[] and back in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java) shows you how to convert it to bytes.