# consolidating bytes in java

Tags: java, byte, long-integer

As part of a program I'm writing I need to consolidate two bytes into a long from an array of bytes.
So assuming this:

```
byte a[] = new byte[2]
a[0] = 0b1000111
a[1] = 0b1111000
```

how can I consolidate them such that

```
long b = 0b10001111111000
```

EDIT: The program will attempt to consolidate anywhere between 2 bytes and 100, just for reference.

Comment: Those two binary values do not fit (each) in a byte.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Why not?

Comment: @Slaks `0b10001110` is `142`.

Comment: Related (and possibly a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Bytes are 8 bits.  Pretend they're unsigned.

Comment: @Slaks Those binary integer literals do not fit in the `byte` primitive data type as shown in the snippet. It won't compile.

Comment: How do you plan on getting a `long` from 100 bytes?  That would overflow.  What outcome would you want in that case?

Answer (score 1):

In order to combine those two bytes you will only need 16 bits.  A short will suffice:

```
short result = (short)(((a[0] & 0xff) << 8) | (a[1] & 0xff))
```

If for some reason, you need the `long` data type, you need only replace the cast with a long.

Comment: @GlennLane How exactly does this work? I like knowing what goes on behind a solution before I use it. Thanks!

Comment: @muttstuffle What this does is it takes the first byte and shifts it so that it is the first 8 bits of a short.  Then we OR the second byte with that to make it the last 8 bits of the short.  So we have a 16 bits containing both of the bytes

Comment: Sorry @Joel, your solution works.  Mind though, if a[0] is negative (-90 or 0xa6), then (short)a[0] gives 0xffa6 (not 0x00a6)... but you're shifting those ff's away so it doesn't matter.  It **would** matter if you were using a wider type like int or long however, in which << 8 would give you 0xffffa600 for int.

Comment: @GlennLane Good point.  Stupid java and its lack of unsigned types.

Comment: @Joel now there's a problem... you're implying a cast on a[1].  If a[1] is negative, you're or'ing 0xffffffffffffff??.  You need to mask a[1] as well.

Comment: ... and the cast on a[0] is unnecessary because it becomes long after and'ing with mask

Comment: ((a[0] & 0xffL) << 8) | (a[1] & 0xffL)     ;-)

Comment: @GlennLane Right, should be good now. Thanks for that, I am just so used to unsigned types! Ha

Comment: And the short snippet won't compile... bitshifting always returns at least an int, never a short, so you would need to cast after shifting.  As well, your a[1] would bring in 0xff?? if it were negative.  Try: (short)(((a[0] & 0xff) << 8) | (a[1] & 0xff))

Answer (score 1):

`java.nio` can do that:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(a).getShort()
```

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` can do this:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

```
BigInteger buffer = new BigInteger(yourByteArray);
long result = buffer.longValue();
```

Note that if your byte array has a value larger than a `long` (eg, you mentioned that you might go up to 100 bytes), `toLong()` will only return the value of the lower value bytes.  `BigInteger`, however, will handle any arbitrary number of bytes.

Comment: Given the added requirement to store up to 100 bytes, this is the solution