# Represent long in least amount of characters

Tags: java, scala

I need to represent both very large and small numbers in the shortest string possible. The numbers are unsigned. I have tried just straight Base64 encode, but for some smaller numbers, the encoded string is longer than just storing the number as a string. What would be the best way to most optimally store a very large or short number in the shortest string possible with it being URL safe?

Comment: For which one? The shortest possible encoding in all circumstances? Gray code? LZW?

Comment: Define "string". What characters are allowed?

Comment: @ccleve latin1 would be preferable

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but I am looking for the shortest possible encoding in all circumstances.

Comment: The "shortest possible encoding in all circumstances" is literally the 8 bytes that compose the long. Unless you give a clearer explanation of what you're looking for, no one is going to be able to help.

Comment: @bkail Ah yes good point. It has to be URL safe.

Comment: Are you looking for a strictly optimal solution, or just a good/convenient mechanism? The optimal solution will be to look at the URI RFC to determine all possible characters, and then write a base N encoder. You're likely better off just using a pre-written base64 encoder; can you clarify what you mean by "longer than just storing the number as a string"? If it's a problem with trailing `=`, then I would just trim those when encoding and restore them (so that the string has a length that is a multiple of 4) before decoding.

Answer (score 4):

> I have tried just straight Base64 encode, but for some smaller numbers, the encoded string is longer than just storing the number as a string

Base64 encoding of binary byte data will make it longer, by about a third. It is not supposed to make it shorter, but to allow safe transport of binary data in formats that are not binary safe.

However, base 64 is more compact than *decimal* representation of a number (or of byte data), even if it is less compact than base 256 (the raw byte data). Encoding your numbers in base 64 directly will make them more compact than decimal. This will do it:

```
private static final String base64Chars =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

static String encodeNumber(long x) {
    char[] buf = new char[11];
    int p = buf.length;
    do {
        buf[--p] = base64Chars.charAt((int)(x % 64));
        x /= 64;
    } while (x != 0);
    return new String(buf, p, buf.length - p);
}

static long decodeNumber(String s) {
    long x = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        int charValue = base64Chars.indexOf(c);
        if (charValue == -1) throw new NumberFormatException(s);
        x *= 64;
        x += charValue;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Using this encoding scheme, `Long.MAX_VALUE` will be the string `H__________`, which is 11 characters long, compared to its decimal representation `9223372036854775807` which is 19 characters long. Numbers up to about 16 million will fit in a mere 4 characters. That's about as short as you'll get it. (Technically there are two other characters which do not need to be encoded in URLs: [`.` and `~`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3). You can incorporate those to get base 66, which would be a smidgin shorter for some numbers, although that seems a bit pedantic.)

Comment: For a simpler implementation (none) that sadly only go to base 36 you can use this (which gives zik0zj): 
  Integer.toString(2147483647, Character.MAX_RADIX)

Comment: For followers, this does produce a "smaller" string than converting a long to 8 bytes then base64 encoding the 8 bytes. However, it's also "a different format" than normal base64 encoding, as it were, so a generic base64 decoder probably won't be able to read it FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on Stephen C's answer, here is a piece of code to convert to base 62 (but you can increase this by adding more characters to the `digits` String (just pick what characters are valid for you):

```
public static String toString(long n) {
   String digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   int base = digits.length();
   String s = "";
   while (n > 0) {
      long d = n % base;
      s = digits.charAt(d) + s;
      n = n / base;
   }
   return s;
}
```

This will never result in the string representation being longer than the digit one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't do any compression, and that you restrict yourself to URL safe characters, then the following procedure will give you the most compact encoding possible.

1. Make a list of all URL safe characters
2. Count them.  Suppose you have N.
3. Represent your number in base N, representing 0 by the first character, 1 by the 2nd and so on.

---

So, what about compression ...

If you assume that the numbers you are representing are uniformly distributed across their range, then there is no real opportunity for compression.

Otherwise, there is *potential* for compression.  If you can reduce the size of the common numbers then you can typically achieve a saving by compression.  This is how Huffman encoding works.

But the downside is that compression at this level is not perfect across the range of numbers.  It reduces the size of some numbers, but it inevitably increases the size of others.

---

So what does this mean for your use-case?

I think it means that you are looking at the problem the wrong way.  You should not be aiming for a minimal encoded size for every number.  You should be aiming to minimize the size on average ... averaged over the actual distribution of your numbers.