# convert long to byte[] returns unreadable format

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I am trying to convert long to bytes because I want to write the time stamp in seconds in a file.
Belwo are the method wich I am using to convert long to bytes[] and how I write them into a file..

What I am getting from the following line:

```
bos.write( ( CSysUtils.longToBytes(CSysUtils.getTSMilli()) ) );
```

is an unreadable code/format:

**code**:

```
public static long getTSSec() {
    Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("getTSSec"));

    return System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
}

public static byte[] longToBytes(long l) {
    byte[] result = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[i] = (byte)(l & 0xFF);
        l >>= 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**write to a file**:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

bos.write( ( CSysUtils.longToBytes(CSysUtils.getTSSec()) ) );
```

Comment: What do you mean "unreadable"? That you can't read it? That your code can't read it back again?

Comment: use these methods here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java

Comment: Is not easier to write it in ascii as a String?

Comment: Why do you want to write them to file as bytes[]? Why not as String.

Comment: @Raf because iin the end i need to convert it to bytes..for an example if i want to erite "s" to a file it should be written as follows: "s".getbytes

Comment: did you try `java.io.DataInput` and `java.io.DataOutput` or `java.io.RandomAccessFile` which implements them both?

Comment: Confusing. You don't even specify the expected format of the output file. For instance, do you expect your longs to be stored in big endian format, little endian?

Comment: In Java, all numeric primitives (including `byte`) are *signed*. Maybe that is confusing things when you look at the data?  I just tested your loop, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do this?:

```
bos.write(Long.toString(CSysUtils.getTSSec()).getBytes());
```

With this, the milliseconds are human readable in the output file.

Is that what you need?