# Convert Double to ByteArray or Array<Byte> Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Given a Double

```
val double = 1.2345
```

How can I convert that to a Kotlin `ByteArray`, and/or `Array<Byte>`?

Whose content would look like the following after converting 1.2345

```
00111111 11110011 11000000 10000011
00010010 01101110 10010111 10001101
```

In Java, there is a sollution that involves `Double.doubleToLongBits()`(A static method of java.lang.Double), but in Kotlin, Double refers to `Kotlin.Double`, which has no such (or any other useful in this situation) method.

I don't mind if a sollution yields `Kotlin.Double` inaccessible in this file. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can still use Java `Double`'s methods, though you will have to use full qualified names:

```
val double = 1.2345
val long = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(double)
```

Then convert it to `ByteArray` in [any way that works in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java), such as

```
val bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(java.lang.Long.BYTES).putLong(long).array()
```

<sup>(note the full qualified name again)</sup>

---

You can then make an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for this:

```
fun Double.bytes() = 
    ByteBuffer.allocate(java.lang.Long.BYTES)
        .putLong(java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(this))
        .bytes()
```

And the usage:

```
val bytes = double.bytes()
```

Comment: Also consider using `import java.lang.Double as JDouble` to turn `java.lang.Double` into `JDouble`

Comment: The `bytes()` method does not seem to exist. Do I have to import something?

Comment: Perfect breaking point when you are in a Multiplatform project

Answer (score 4):

It looks like some convinient methods were added since your answer and you can achieve the same with

```
val double = 1.2345
ByteBuffer.allocate(java.lang.Double.BYTES)
     .putDouble(double).array()
```