# Save and load double values in shared preferences

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `Location` object and I want to save it in shared preferences, but I can't because it's an object, so I thought of saving latitude and longitude in shared preferences instead, but the problem is that `location.getLatitude()` and `location.getLongitude()` return `Double` and I can't save `Double` in shared preferences, however I can save `Float`, so my question is: Is it a good idea to save latitude and longitude as floats instead of doubles? Is there another way that I missed?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't save Double in shared preferences" ?

Comment: There is no `putDouble` method in the SharedPreferences object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604849/where-to-save-android-gps-latitude-longitude-points

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319237/cant-put-double-sharedpreferences

Comment: I read those but I don't know how to use `Double.doubleToLongBits` in kotlin

Comment: There's a nice search bar on StackOverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397116/convert-double-to-bytearray-or-arraybyte-kotlin

Comment: I think the Location object is Parcelable, though, so just store that