# neatly convert byte[] to long[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i have an array of bytes which needs to be repackaged to an array of longs. the input byte array is of unknown size (roughly from 0 to a few hundred). the long array needs to come out **right aligned** ie the lowest index long should be padded with zeros and all others should be full of the input bytes:
. (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11) --> (xxxxb0b1b2b3, b4b5b6b7b8b9b10b11)

where b1,b2 etc is a given byte.
i have a solution but it isnt very neat or readable:

```
// outArr has length (inArr.length+7)/8

for (int i = 0; i < inArr.length ; i++) {     
    outArr[outArr.length - i/8 - 1] |= ((long)inArr[inArr.length - i - 1]) << (i % 8) * 8;
    }
```

is there a less ugly way of doing this?

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java

Answer (score 2):

There may be more elegant ways of doing it, but one way could be to use a java.nio buffer to convert it. Because of the need to align the input array to 8 bytes chunks, it requires a few more steps:

```
int padding = outArr.length * 8 - inArr.length;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(inArr.length + padding)
                              .put(new byte[padding]).put(inArr);
buffer.flip();
buffer.asLongBuffer().get(outArr);
```

Comment: `ByteByffer.wrap(inArr)` is yetl a bit shorter. And `order(LITTLE_ENDIAN)` might be needed. But indeed ByteBuffer is _the_ solution.

Comment: Yes, that would be shorter, but it would not solve the _whole_ problem because of the needed padding, as you would need to have a correctly padded byte array first. That's what I'm building building the byte buffer with two `put()` and `flip()`. Regarding the order; the default `BIG_ENDIAN` is the correct one.