# How to make a byte array with first eight bytes as current timestamp?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I am making a byte array with predefined size as shown below:

```
private byte[] newPayload() {
  byte[] payload = new byte[100];
  Arrays.fill(payload, (byte) 1);
  return payload;
}
```

Now I want to add 8 bytes of current timestamp in the same byte array in front of it.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

So first eight bytes will be current timestamp and remaining 92 bytes will be same what I am doing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ByteBuffer to convert `long` to `byte[]`. Also you can use `System.arraycopy` to copy this `byte[]` to the mail array. Please refer the below code.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE);
buffer.putLong(time);
byte[] timeBytes = buffer.array();
System.arraycopy(timeBytes, 0, payload, 0, timeBytes.length);
```

Comment: It looks like, I cannot find BYTES for Long class? I only see size?

Comment: you can try (`Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE`)

Comment: Also let's say If I have this new byte array, now how can I extract first 8 bytes from payload byte array and convert them to long and print it out?

Comment: hope this will help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java

Comment: yes but how will I extract the first eight bytes only from the byte array?

Comment: you can use `Arrays#copyOfRange` to extract the bytes to a separate array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: so something like this? `byte[] newBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(payload, 0, 7);`

Comment: yup.. that should work.. to be accurate you can give `byte[] newBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(payload, 0, (Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE - 1));`