# How to get an int type hash using message digest for bloom filters

Tags: java, hash, bloom-filter, message-digest

I am trying to implement a bloom filter in java and one type of hash needs to be using the message digest. During the add method the other hashes I have created are used to set the index of the bitset to true. I need to create a hash using message digest to achieve the same goal but I cannot find a way to return an int.
My add method and attempt at the hash:

```
public void add(String element) {
    int index = Math.abs(element.hashCode())%size;
    int index1 = myHash(element);

    //  int index2 = mdHash(element);

    b.set(index, true); 
    b.set(index1, true);
}

public int mdHash(String message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(message.getBytes()); 
    byte[] digest = md.digest();       
    return ;
}
```

How can I create a hash using the digest that also can be used to set an index to true?

Comment: You seem to have a typo: mdHash > myHash.

Comment: If you want to convert a byte array to a long, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java

Answer (score 0):

For a Bloom filter, using SHA-256 isn't normally needed: it is slow. Instead, I would use e.g. Murmur hash. Or just hashCode(), and then use [another hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664014/what-integer-hash-function-are-good-that-accepts-an-integer-hash-key/12996028#12996028) to generate a 64 hash.

Then, from that hash, you can generate many number as needed for the Bloom filter, for example as follows (see also the [fastfilter_java project](https://github.com/FastFilter/fastfilter_java/blob/master/fastfilter/src/main/java/org/fastfilter/bloom/Bloom.java)):

```
public void add(long key) {
    long hash = Hash.hash64(key, seed);
    long a = (hash >>> 32) | (hash << 32);
    long b = hash;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        data[Hash.reduce((int) (a >>> 32), arraySize)] |= 1L << a;
        a += b;
    }
}
```