# Fastest way to convert an byte[8] to long

Tags: java, arrays, byte, long-integer, bytebuffer

I want to convert an array of 8 bytes (`new byte[8]`) to a `long`. I've found many solutions but which one is the fastest? I'm not sure how I can *benchmark* these solutions.

Here are a couple of solutions that look good to me:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456641/5647659
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29132118/5647659
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27610608/5647659

Or maybe you have an even better solution?

***Note:** I don't need to convert them back to an array of bytes*

Comment: If it is a bottleneck for your usage, benchmark the solutions to see which one is fastest.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how I can benchmark these solutions"* Then see: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/5221149)

Comment: #3 would be the fastest.

Comment: *"better solution?"* The simplest would be `ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getLong()` where you can specify whether you want `BIG_ENDIAN` or `LITTLE_ENDIAN` byte order. The default is big-endian, also known as network-order.