# How kotlin compiler evaluates expressions like val bytes = 0b00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000

Tags: kotlin

What will be the output for  val bytes = 0b00000001_00000000_00000000_00000000

I have tried printing it it displays 16777216 and even tried printing its type is comes out to be Int even tried chat gpt it says it will evaluate it into an array of type bytes but when trying to iterate over it it says this has not method iterator().

Comment: Kotlin isn't lying to you (though apparently ChatGPT is). That code gives you an `Int` whose value is defined by the integer literal (the `0b` prefix means the literal is in binary). If you want to create a byte array then perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403881/creating-bytearray-in-kotlin and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179257/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-a-bytearray-and-then-convert-it-back-to-an-int-with can help you.

Comment: You may also want to read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#literal-constants-for-numbers