# How to I convert to Unsigned Integer?

Tags: java

I have some data which I'm reading from a Binary File, I see that the data is of unsigned type. How can I read the file in Java to convert it correctly? Right now I'm having to do

```
 byte[] bdata = new byte[DataLen];
 Integer.reverseBytes(ByteBuffer.wrap(bdata).getInt(0)) & (-1L >>> 32)
```

to get the data correctly. Is there a easier way to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

there is no unsigned integer in java, but there is `long`, which can hold whole unsigned integer. You can convert between long, and bytes [How do I convert Long to byte[] and back in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java)

Comment: I feel like this was not actually OPs question. They have to read a file that contains an unsigned type, maybe written by another program. And want to be able to read it correctly. Which is a job for `ByteBuffer`, as explained in the linked duplicate.