# Zero-Allocation-Hashing murmur3: hashChars() and hashBytes() produce different output

Tags: java, murmurhash

I am not sure if I am using `murmur3` (**OpenHFT**'s [zero-allocation-hashing](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Zero-Allocation-Hashing)) function correctly but the result seems different for `hashChars()` and `hashBytes()`

```
// Using zero-allocation-hashing 0.16  
String input = "abc123";
System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashChars(input));
System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashBytes(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

**Output:**

```
-4878457159164508227
-7432123028918728600
```

The latter one produces the same output as **Guava** lib.

Which function should be used for `String` inputs?

Shouldn't both functions produce the same result?

**Update:**

How can I get same output as :

```
Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().asLong();
Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().toString()
```

using `zero-allocation-hashing` lib which seems to be faster than `Guava`

Comment: You could implement your own `Access`, but an efficient implementation is only possible with ASCII input, as this API assumes random access to the resulting byte sequence (and creating a UTF-8 representation beforehand would contradict the “zero-allocation” goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption regarding `UTF-8` is not correct, it holds for `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`.

```java
String input = "abc123";

System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashChars(input));
System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashBytes(
  input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)
));
```

gives:

```text
-4878457159164508227
-4878457159164508227
```

## Additional Answer

For the desired:

```java
Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().asLong();
```

this:

```java
LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashBytes(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

seems to work (please test more!)

The (hex) string conversion is sort of a problem, since the guava hash creates (really) 128 bits (16 bytes, 2 longs), whereas "your lib" gives us only 64 bits!

<s>Half of the digits i can reproduce with:
...</s>

thx to:

- [How do I convert Long to byte[] and back in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4485128/592355)
- https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.java#L412

---

With your help (sorry first time encounter this lib), I could finally:

```java
System.out.println("Actual:   " +
    toHexString(
        LongTupleHashFunction.murmur_3().hashBytes(
            input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        )
    )
);
```

where:

```java
private static final String toHexString(long[] hashLongs) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hashLongs.length * Long.BYTES * 2);
    for (long lng : hashLongs)
        for (int i = 0; i < Long.BYTES; i++) {
            byte b = (byte) (lng >> (i * Long.BYTES));
            sb.append(HEX_DIGITS[(b >> 4) & 0xf]).append(HEX_DIGITS[b & 0xf]);
        }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static final char[] HEX_DIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
```

Comment: I want same output as `Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().asLong()` and `Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().toString()` using `zero-allocation-hashing` lib which seems to be faster than `Guava`

Comment: ..i thought it was "additional question" ;p

Comment: lol. you got me :p

Comment: see updates ...

Comment: thanks. any idea about the 2nd part i.e. `toString()` equivalent which produce 128-bit hex string I think?

Comment: also working on this (but it can also ruin the "seems to be faster"!?;)

Comment: I would love to see (and learn) the benchmark code and stats.

Comment: "I would love to see (and learn) the benchmark code and stats." > me2 ! lol

Comment: `LongTupleHashFunction.xx128().hashBytes(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` can be used to get long[]. I have also used the same function reference for hex conversion but something seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a char and byte **[are different](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)** in Java:

- `char` size is 16 bits, using the Unicode character set
- `byte` actually respond to it's name, 8 bits long

This difference becomes crucial when we consider different characters:  considering a simple character like 'A' - in Unicode, it's represented by the hexadecimal number 0x0041, so in our example:

```java
String input = "A";
byte[] bytes = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashChars(input));
System.out.println(LongHashFunction.murmur_3().hashBytes(bytes));
```

`hashChars` is working with two bytes (0x00, 0x41), while `hashBytes` is working with one byte (0x41) -- this is why you will get different results.

Which function to use really depends on your requirements: if you're hashing strings and you wanna ignore the underlying encoding, use `hashChars()`. If you care about the specific byte representation, use hashBytes().

Comment: I want same output as `Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().asLong()` and `Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putString(input, Charsets.UTF_8).hash().toString()` using `zero-allocation-hashing` lib which seems to be faster than `Guava`